# Unpermitted Parameter error in Rails for nested nested form submission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, model-view-controller, nested-attributes, model-associations

I'm trying to create a quiz builder where a user builds a quiz that is added to the `Quiz` model, a question that is in the `QuizQuestions` model and answer choices in and `AnswerChoices` model.

The Quiz is the main controller. From the edit page, the user can add a new question and select an answer choice type The question model is nested under the quiz model. Then the answer model is nested under the quiz model.

However, saving the form does not save the answer choices to the database, and there is an `unpermitted parameter` message, but all parameters are permitted, and it happens even with one paramter.

The controller looks like:

```
def edit
        @quiz = Quiz.find(params[:id])

        @quiz_questions = @quiz.quiz_questions.all 
        
        @quiz.quiz_questions.build(quiz_params) unless @quiz.quiz_questions.present?

    end

    def update
        @quiz = Quiz.find(params[:id])
        @quiz_questions = @quiz.quiz_questions

        if @quiz.update(quiz_params)
            redirect_to edit_quiz_path, notice: "Successfully upated quiz"
        else
           redirect_to admin_path,  notice: "UNSUCCESSFULLY added quiz"
        
        end

    end
def quiz_params
    params.require(:quiz).permit(
        :quiz_name,
         quiz_questions_attributes: [:id, :question, :quiz_id],
         quiz_answers_attributes: [:id, :question_id]
         
    
    )
end
```

The models (in different files):

```
class Quiz < ApplicationRecord

    #Associations
    has_many :quiz_questions, foreign_key: :quiz_id
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :quiz_questions

end

class QuizQuestion < ApplicationRecord


    #ASSOCIATIONS
    belongs_to :quiz, foreign_key: :quiz_id

    has_many :quiz_answers, foreign_key: :question_id

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :quiz_answers, allow_destroy: true

end

class QuizAnswer < ApplicationRecord

    #Associations
        belongs_to :quiz_question, foreign_key: :question_id
        
end
```

quiz/edit.html.erb

```
<div >
        <%= form_with model: @quiz do |newQuiz| %>

        <div >

              <h3> <%= newQuiz.label :quiz_name, "QUIZ: " %></h3>

              <%= newQuiz.text_field :quiz_name, %>
            
        </div>
                               

        <%= newQuiz.fields_for :quiz_questions do |questionData| %>

                    
            <div>
                <h3> <%= questionData.label :question, "Question" %></h3>
                <%= questionData.text_field :question %>
            </div>


            <%= questionData.hidden_field :quiz_id, value: 1 %>


            <%= newQuiz.fields_for :quiz_answers do |answerData| %>

                <%= answerData.text_field :id %>


                <%= answerData.hidden_field :question_id, value: 1 %>
                
            
             <% end %>
                   
        <% end %>
                

    </div>
        <%= newQuiz.submit "SAVE" %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

The error says:

```
Unpermitted parameter: :quiz_answers. Context: { controller: QuizzesController, action: update, request: #<ActionDispatch::Request:...>, params: {"_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "quiz"=>{"quiz_name"=>"Test Quiz 1", "quiz_questions_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"question"=>"This is a test question?", "quiz_id" => "1", "id"=>"1"}}, "quiz_answers"=>{"id"=>"1", "question_id"=>"1"}}, "commit"=>"SAVE", "controller"=>"quizzes", "action"=>"update", "id"=>"1"} }
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you are nesting your models in 3 levels (A `Quiz` contains multiple `QuizQuestion`s, and a `QuizQuestion` contains multiple `QuizAnswer`s.

So to use the `accepts_nested_attributes` option, your input parameters should also be nested accordingly, e.g. your `quiz_params` are supposed to look like

```
def quiz_params
    params.require(:quiz).permit(
        :quiz_name,
         quiz_questions_attributes: [
           :id,
           :question,
           :quiz_id,
           quiz_answers_attributes: [:id, :question_id]
        ],
    )
end
```

The view should be build accordingly, that you have some input fields for the answers for every single question the user enters, e.g.

```
<div>
  <%= form_with model: @quiz do |newQuiz| %>
    <div>
      <h3> <%= newQuiz.label :quiz_name, "QUIZ: " %></h3>
      <%= newQuiz.text_field :quiz_name, %>
    </div>

    <%= newQuiz.fields_for :quiz_questions do |questionData| %>
      <div>
        <h3> <%= questionData.label :question, "Question" %></h3>
        <%= questionData.text_field :question %>
      </div>
      <%= questionData.hidden_field :quiz_id, value: 1 %>
      
      <%= questionData.fields_for :quiz_answers do |answerData| %>
        <%= answerData.text_field :id %>
        <%= answerData.hidden_field :question_id, value: 1 %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <%= newQuiz.submit "SAVE" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

On a sidenote, you should work a bit of your formatting, you are actually closing one div more than you are opening, which is a bit difficult to spot in the code as you wrote it...

Comment: Thanks, so initially I had the parameter nested as you have it, but I was still getting the error. I changed `newQuiz` to `questionData` for the answer input fields, and now there seems to be no error, but the data for the answers is not showing up in the table

Comment: Did you update the `quiz_params` function as I suggested too? Also, did you try and use the debugger inside the controller to check if the parameters are actually coming as expected, and there are no errors on the objects after save?